# why i have to call or declare the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js in each partial page in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

why i have to call or declare this jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js in each partial page where i need validations.

I have already define the js in master layout.

Thank You for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why i have to call or declare this jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
>   in each partial page where i need validations.

No, you don't need to do that. Adding it once in the Layout is more than enough.

Of course if you add some partial HTML to your DOM using for example an AJAX call and this HTML contains form elements that need to be bound to unobtrusive validation you need to force their parsing using the following the `parse` method that you need to invoke immediately after adding or replacing some elements to the DOM:

```
$("form").removeData("validator");
$("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
```